# File Input Ouput, reading multiple files in C

Tags: c

im trying to do a practice problem from my textbook and im having alot of trouble. Im trying to open files in an range that the user specifies, and doing calculations, moving from file to file. Each file has the following format file05-data-(int 1-99). and the whole file is called practice.exe My main function has the follwing parameters and looks like... say user enters the executable `./practice 10 13`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE* newfile;
    int i = argc;
    while (i<arvf[])   */im pretty sure i<arvf doesnt work but how do i capture
                         the range inputed by the user,and open each one?*/
       {
        newfile = fopen(("file05-data-%d.txt",i) "r")
        i = i + 1
       }
```

Im confused on how to take the user input, and opening the files in the range that the user inputed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: would fscanf be appropriate here?

Comment: or fgets? Its just im not sure what buffer sizes and the parameters of these functions are

Answer (score 0):

E.g

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    FILE *file;
    if(argc != 3){
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage >practice start_num end_num\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int start = atoi(argv[1]);
    int end = atoi(argv[2]);
    if(!(1 <= start && start <= 99 && 1<= end && end <= 99 && start <= end)){
        fprintf(stderr, "Specifying the range of values must be 1-99.\n");
        return 2;
    }
    char filename[FILENAME_MAX];
    int no;
    for(no = start ; no <= end ; ++no){
        snprintf(filename, sizeof(filename), "file05-data-%d.txt", no);
        if(NULL==(file=fopen(filename, "r"))){
            fprintf(stderr, "%s can't open.\n", filename);
            //return 3;
            continue;
        }
        /* input && output
        char line[128];
        while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)){
            printf("%s", line);
        }
        */
        fclose(file);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
./practice 10 13
```

This is fine, but your usage of argc and argv is incorrect. I am assuming here that you are trying to open file# 10, 11, 12, 13.

1st put a check whether you are running the binary with right no of inputs (I think you are asking for two arguments) by:

```
if(argc!=3) 
{
   // print error msg & exit
}
```

And to build the file names:

```
char newfile[MAX_SIZE];
for(i=atoi(argv[1]); i<atoi(argv[2]); i++)
    {
        snprintf(newfile, "file-data-%d", i);
        //open this file, read data, and then loop to the next file
    }
```

That's it!